# Can't run global babel-node in es2015 mode

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-node

so when I install these packages locally they work, but when installed globally (and removed them locally)

```
 npm i babel-cli -g
 npm i -g babel-preset-es2015
 npm i -g babel-preset-es2015-node
```

seems like that flag isn't setting es2016-node to look in the global package list. anyways this following error occurs:

> npm run start myfile.js

```
babel-node --presets es2015-node -- bin/myScript.js "myfile.js"

/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:395
          throw new Error("Couldn't find preset " + (0, _stringify2.default)(val) + " relative to directory " + (0, _stringify2.default)(dirname));
          ^

Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015-node" relative to directory "/Users/user/project/bin"
    at /usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:395:17
    at Array.map (native)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:387:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:370:10)

npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "start" "myfile.js"
npm ERR! node v6.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! project@0.0.0 start: `babel-node --presets es2015-node -- bin/myScript.js "myfile.js"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@0.0.0 start script 'babel-node --presets es2015-node -- bin/myScript.js "myfile.js"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the project package,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hint is in the error message:

> Couldn't find preset "es2015-node" **relative to directory "/Users/user/project/bin"**

Install the presets locally and have them saved as dependencies in your `package.json` by using the `--save` flag:

```
npm install --save babel-preset-es2015-node babel-preset-es2015
```

It is a wise move by Babel that presets are looked for locally only. This way you are forced to produce a module that is portable by describing the necessary dependencies required for its operation within the `package.json`, which are then installed by users via `npm install`.

Comment: wouldn't it be wiser to build the es2015 within the babel-node, so people can use flag to fast configure it instead of dealing with a global executable looking for dirpath modules/configs?

Comment: Babel isn't exclusively an ES6 -> ES5 transpiler, hence the configuration necessary for it to do this.

Comment: maybe not, but i feel that babel-node without es2015 is inadaquete as a node runner as it doesn't understand module pattern, destructuring and perhaps other important features, why not have babel-node as a separate package that include babel-node-es2015.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm update
```

solved the issue for me.

Comment: i think babel recently adopted the es2015 as 2016 is almost ending.